# How to access multiple values of field collection in node.tpl?

Tags: entities

I have field collection for one of my content type.
The fields in field collection are

- Title
- Body
- Image

  The field collection can have many values at a time.
  I tried to get the values using entity load in foreach loop but its not loading anything.
  Also i am embedding a node in field collection which is also not working any guesses why its not showing node embed.

  Here is my code

  ```
  foreach($field as $my ) {
    $section_content_id = $my["value"];

    $field_info = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($section_content_id));

    $section_value = $field_info[$section_content_id]->field_title[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"];

    $section_desc = $field_info[$section_content_id]->field_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"];

  }
  ```

Comment: I am not able to understand the question, sorry. Please let us know what the `$field` variable in the `foreach` loop is, I guess it is a field of type field collection. And what do you mean by "not loading anything"? Did you try this code with a node which has values in the fields of the field collection? I also did not understand what did you mean by "embedding a node in field collection". Do you mean you have an field of type node reference inside your field collection?

Comment: On a side note, loading of entities in a template files is not recommended. You should be doing that [using preprocess functions](https://drupal.org/node/223430).

Comment: Embedding node means i embedding a node title using node title.
My first problem is solved now i am able to see my loaded data in field collection.
But there is problem with node embed it is node embedding the title using node embed in field colletion.